# Pandas read csv ignore commas, one column per line

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a txt file that has the following format

```
a 1 blah
b 2 blah,inc
c 3 foo,inc
```

i want to read it into a `df` using `read_csv()` but the commas are giving me an error and I don't want to skip with `error_bad_lines=False`.

How do I read it into a `df` ONE column per line? Or should I use another method?

Comment: try `sep='\s+'` or parameter `delim_whitespace=True`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need change default separator `,` to `s\+` for white-space sep:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""
a 1 blah
b 2 blah,inc
c 3 foo,inc"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), sep='\s+', header=None, names=['a','b','c'])
print (df)
   a  b         c
0  a  1      blah
1  b  2  blah,inc
2  c  3   foo,inc
```

For one column use some separator which is NOT in data like `|` or `¥`:

```
temp=u"""
a 1 blah
b 2 blah,inc
c 3 foo,inc"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), sep='|', header=None, names=['a'])
print (df)
              a
0      a 1 blah
1  b 2 blah,inc
2   c 3 foo,inc
```

Another solution with [`read_fwf`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html):

```
df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(temp), header=None, colspecs=[(0, 100)])

print (df)
              0
0      a 1 blah
1  b 2 blah,inc
2   c 3 foo,inc
```

Comment: i guess the not in data approach is little dangerous, in that you never know what will be in the data. but it works for now.

Comment: Yes, it depends of data. But I think obviosly `¥` is not in data.

Comment: I add another solution, please check - [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#files-with-fixed-width-columns)

Answer (score 1):

I think that `pd.read_csv(delim_whitespace=True)`, should do the trick.